# How to categorize text in a pandas dataframe based on the number of positive and negative keywords

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this:

```
          Tweets                      negative_keywords positive_keywords
0   Şanlıurfa'da DAEŞ ile                       []            []
1   Hacettepe Üni. Araştırması                  []            []
2   Kadına şiddetin suç olduğu                [suç]           []
3   Suriyeli'lerin fal bakabilme                []            []
4   Hastaneye git Suriyeli. PTT ye              []      [kardeşi]
```

I want to add a new column which is called neutral_keywords. If negative_keywords and positive_keywords are [] at the same time, neutral_keywords should take the value of [neutral]. Otherwise, it should take the value of []. Then, I should add a new column based on the values of positive, negative and neutral. So, my new pandas data frame should look like this:

```
          Tweets                      negative_keywords positive_keywords keyword_category  keyword_category
0   Şanlıurfa'da DAEŞ ile                       []            []             [neutral]       neutral
1   Hacettepe Üni. Araştırması                  []            []             [neutral]       neutral 
2   Kadına şiddetin suç olduğu                [suç]           []                []           negative
3   Suriyeli'lerin fal bakabilme                []            []             [neutral]       neutral
4   Hastaneye git Suriyeli. PTT ye              []         [kardeşi]           []            positive
```

How can I do that?

Comment: look at apply function in pandas

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you help me with that?

Comment: What should `keyword_category` be when `negative_keywords` and `positive_keywords` are not `[]`?  In your example, the data in row 4 (`'Hastaneye git Suriyeli. PTT ye'`) is different in the top and bottom code snippets.

Comment: @Bill Sorry Bill, I edited it right now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I solved the question on my own :) Thanks everyone :)

Comment: It's still not clear what `keyword_category` should be when `negative_keywords` and `positive_keywords` are not `'[]'`  Can you answer that?  Also, in your second code snippet the data frame has two columns named `'keyword_category'` which is a bit confusing.  Should one column label be `'neutral_keywords'`?

Comment: For each row:

If positive and negative categories are [] and neutral category is [neutral], the value of my keyword category should be : Neutral

If positive category and neutral category is [] and negative category is [text], the value of my keyword should be: Negative

If negative and neutral category is [] and positive category is [text], the value of my keyword should be : Positive

My code did not work now. Can you help?

Comment: You still didn't mention what happens when both positive category and neutral category is `[text]`.  Can you explain or confirm that this will not occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data in `df` are lists of strings, here's how I would do it.

```
n_negative = df['negative_keywords'].apply(len)
n_positive = df['positive_keywords'].apply(len)
df['keyword_category'] = 'neutral'
df.loc[n_negative > 0, 'keyword_category'] = 'negative'
df.loc[n_positive > 0, 'keyword_category'] = 'positive'  # May over-write negatives
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                           Tweets negative_keywords positive_keywords keyword_category
0           Şanlıurfa'da DAEŞ ile                []                []          neutral
1      Hacettepe Üni. Araştırması                []                []          neutral
2      Kadına şiddetin suç olduğu             [suç]                []         negative
3    Suriyeli'lerin fal bakabilme                []                []          neutral
4  Hastaneye git Suriyeli. PTT ye                []         [kardeşi]         positive
```

One alternative you might want to consider is:

```
n_negative = df['negative_keywords'].apply(len)
n_positive = df['positive_keywords'].apply(len)
df['keyword_category'] = 'neutral'
df.loc[n_negative > n_positive, 'keyword_category'] = 'negative'
df.loc[n_positive > n_negative, 'keyword_category'] = 'positive'
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# define a function which returns True if all are empty lists
all_empty = lambda x: all(not lst for lst in x)
# apply function to the two columns to create a mask
mask = df[['negative_keywords', 'positive_keywords']].apply(all_empty, axis=1)
# initialize the neutral_keywords column
df['neutral_keywords'] = [[]] * len(mask)
# update the neutral_keywords column where the mask is True
df.loc[mask, 'neutral_keywords'] = [['neutral']] * mask.sum()
df
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be an alternative solution.

```
df["keyword_category"] = ['negative' if n else 'positive' if p else 'neutral' 
                            for n, p in zip(df['negative_keywords'], df['positive_keywords'])]
```

Result:

```
                           Tweets negative_keywords positive_keywords keyword_category
0            Şanlıurfada DAEŞ ile                []                []          neutral
1      Hacettepe Üni. Araştırması                []                []          neutral
2      Kadına şiddetin suç olduğu             [suç]                []         negative
3     Suriyelilerin fal bakabilme                []                []          neutral
4  Hastaneye git Suriyeli. PTT ye                []         [kardeşi]         positive
```